# Creation of user fails after deletion of user with same signInName

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I can successfully create users in an Azure AD B2C tenant through the graph api. I can delete the user as well.

When I try to insert a user with the same signInName again, the request fails with this message:

```
"odata.error": {
"code": "Request_BadRequest",
"message": {
  "lang": "en",
  "value": "Another object with the same value for property signInNames already exists."
},
"date": "2016-10-11T15:53:58",
"requestId": "911fcff7-f2f0-4126-aa1e-3c03a757ac0d",
"values": [
  {
    "item": "PropertyName",
    "value": "signInNames"
  },
  {
    "item": "PropertyErrorCode",
    "value": "ObjectConflict"
  }
]
}
```

- After I wait some minutes (5-20?) I can successfully insert the user with the original signInName.
- After successful deletion the user is not visible when I list all users.
- Renaming the user before deletion works fine but I can still not create the user with the original signInName.

Is it possible to speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the same issue in Azure AD.

I Don't think there is anything you can do in your code to speed this up. (Azure AD PMs can answer the question of: what is the real SLA for a delete operation to completely propagate through the system)

I guess all you can do is to consider this error as if the user is actually there when you get this error (Although you can see it in the list).

Not sure about your exact scenario, but this was a really edge case for us.

Another workaround that we were thinking about in our case was: not to delete a user at all and just remove their roles if there is a chance that the user with same ID is needed later on

Because when the user is deleted the ObjectID or UserKey changes and we had references in our system to that ObjectId and that object ID will not exist in Azure AD anymore so we decided to keep the users in most cases unless we really had to delete them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was afraid to hear that.

Answer (score 2):

When you created the service-principal, you also created an application.
use this command to also remove the application:
remove-azurerdadapplication -objectId [key]

Comment: Damn, you saved the day. Thanks!

Comment: This indeed explains the case for any type of CLI to Azure.